# Percentage passed, between two moving points

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Ok, i am terrible in math. But i have this problem:

I have 0 and x as global min and max, and that point N is moving across those two points. But then i have a local min and max, and i would have to calculate the percentage passed from local min and max. Let me illustrate this:

```
        Local Min                 Local Max
```

(start)______|__________(N)____________|___________________(finish)

How would i calculate the percentage passed between local min and local max, if N has the value between start and finish, but local min and local max value changes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question correctly. Do you want to calculate the persentage of $N$ wrt $x$? How do these local min and max come into the play? Maybe you can give an example to clarify?

Comment: start = 0,
finish = 100,
local_min = 20,
local_max = 40,
N = 30,
I want the percentage for N between local_min and local_max in this case it's 50% if i am not mistaken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what percent of the way from local_min to local_max is $N$, you would compute this as 
$$\frac{N-\text{local_min}}{(\text{local_max})-(\text{local_min})}$$
Then convert the resulting value to a percent.